# Vf controller order of execution

Tags: visualforce

If i have a vf page associated with the controller and extention controllers like below

```
<apex:page controller="con1" extensions="ext1,ext2,ext3"/>
```

and i have same method with btnAct() defined in all the controller and extensions controller and this method is associates with the vf page like

```
<apex:commandButton name="call"  action="btnAct()"/>
```

which class method will call and why ?

Answer (score 3):

If extension Controller is defined than first it searches into Extension Controller in the order they are defined. like in your case `first it will search in ext1 then ext2 and then in ext3 then in Standard Controller`.

So in your case `ext1.btnAct()` will be called.

Comment: Your answer is correct for now, but it is worth noting that this behavior is not defined in any Visualforce documentation and might change in the future. It's best to avoid ambiguity and keep your function names separate.

Comment: Yes i agree with you @sfdcfox

Comment: Note that in V28 of VF Developers Guide - it does describe the order of resolution as leftmost first - see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_controller_extension.htm

Comment: Does this hold during initialization where the controller is passed to the constructor of an extensions?, is the order still leftmost first?

Answer (score 2):

simple answer - `ext1.btnAct()` will be called. It will be called as a first extention where user action should be placed